# How to differentiate between string and other args

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I am trying to parse arguments in python code sent from slack... what does this mean is when someone types a command in slack I want to differentiate based on string and other args.

for eg in slack if I use !command inc-number some string and then sometimes
!command inc-number word how could I differentiate both

===============================================================================

```
def update(self,*args):

    inc = args[0]
    id = self.getincsysid(inc) # this func gets the sysid of inc to be update in servicenow.

    request = 'api/now/table/incident/'
    service_now_url = service now url

    url = service_now_url + request + id
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

    # I am stuck here how to differentiate if args1 is a string.
    if args[1] == 'string': #do below 
        requests.put(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers, json= 
    {'comments': args})
        return 'inc updated'
    elif args[1]=='word':
        impact = 'imapct1'
        criticality= 'urgency1'
        requests.put(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers, json={'impact': 
    impact, 'criticality': urgency})

    else:
        return 'none matched'
```

Comment: If you're asking how you can differentiate **a string** from **a word**, you can't (unless you have some other info): can we refine the question as differentiate **a string with spaces** and **a string without spaces**?

Comment: so what i am sending from slack is !command incnumber  work done (this is going to notes field)and in another case, I am doing !command incnumber p1

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing if args[1] is a string use

```
if type(args[1]) = str:
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty difficult to differentiate a **word** from a **string**, mainly because  a `word` **IS** a `string`.
If we take as an example for a `word` the string `"p1"` and an example for a `phrase` the string `"work done"`, we may define a `word` as a set of one or more characters not containing a space, and a `phrase` as a set of words separed by a space.

Starting by this assumption, our `args[1]` is a `phrase` if contains at least one space (we *should* also verify that it contains at least 2 characters...), else it's a `word` if it contains at least 1 character, else is something wrong:

```
if " " in args[1]: #do below 
    requests.put(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers, json= 
{'comments': args})
    return 'inc updated'
elif len(args[1])>0:
    impact = 'imapct1'
    criticality= 'urgency1'
    requests.put(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers, json={'impact': 
impact, 'criticality': urgency})

else:
    return 'none matched'
```

Answer (score 0):

Slack will always return the complete user input as one big string. So you need to implement a parse to transform that string into arguments in accordance with your syntax design.

They are many ways to approach this. I usually use a syntax where a space is used as delimiter to identify each argument plus `"` can be used to encapsulate a longer sentence with multiple words as one argument.

I guess your best approach would be to use existing parsers. e.g. [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) to parse the input from Slack.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035702/python-string-argument-parsing) for examples on how shlex works.

Comment: splitting arg is not a issue , i am facing issue with how to tell my function that sometime fargs will be a string sometimes it can be just a letter or say a word.